# QTableView.setColumnHidden() alternative

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

Let's suppose I have a table with 30 columns, and want to use  QSqlTableModel/QTableView and show only 5 columns. Is there some other way besides 25 times calling a setColumnHidden() function?

```
model = QSqlTableModel(self)
model.setTable("table")
...
view = QTableView()
view.setModel(model)
...
#insane:
view.setColumnHidden(0, True)
view.setColumnHidden(4, True)
view.setColumnHidden(6, True)
view.setColumnHidden(7, True)
view.setColumnHidden(9, True)
view.setColumnHidden(10, True)
view.setColumnHidden(11, True)
...
view.setColumnHidden(29, True)
```

And what if DBA add some new columns that I don't want user to see. Making changes to all installed apps to add some new view.setColumnHidden(n, True) rows? Not so practical.

Maybe there is some Qt function like view.setColumnsShown([1,2,3,5,8]) I'm not aware of?

Comment: Hi, well, QSqlTableModel is really useful but in your case, i'm not sure if it's the best choice. You use this class but then, you want to show only 12% of your model and you are worried about what will happen if a new column appears. Maybe you should use QStandardItemModel and select only columns you want to show ? It's totally up to you to write the correct SQL query to select what you want in your database and it's probably faster.

Comment: Ok, but using  QStandardItemModel with Sql database? How to do that, and why? You're right that the alternative is using QSqlQueryModel.

Comment: How to do that, well a QStandardItemModel can be considered as a matrices of QStandardItem. So you can use `QStandardItemModel::setItem(int row, int col, QStandardItem *item)`. In each item, you put one data of your database. Why doing that ? To have a total control on your model and to be more efficient (I have never performed performance testing between these two techniques so I'm not sure about this point). The only disadvantage is instead of writing `model.setTable("table")`, you have to write more lines of code to create your model (about 20 with a loop to give you an idea).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define your own `setColumnsShown()` function:

```
from sets import Set

def setColumnsShown(view, showcols):
    allcols = Set(range(0, view.model().columnCount()))
    for col in allcols.difference(showcols):
        view.setColumnHidden(col, True)
```

To handle the case where new columns may be added, you could connect the [`columnsInserted()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#columnsInserted) signal of `QSqlTableModel` to a handler function that re-calls `setColumnsShown`.

Comment: Thanks, your code is similar to Chernobyl's but very elegant (py style). I like it. I'll accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there isn't this function, but if you want do this automatically you can write your own function or code snippet, whick will work as you want. Unfortunately I don't familiar with Qt+Python but in C++ it can be done with this code. It is a few loops, so I think that you be able to write same code with Python syntaxis. Also I wrote comments, to show how exactly this code works.

```
QList<int> list;//create list where we set number of columns to be shown
list<< 1<<2;//write in list numbers of columns
    int c = ui->tableView->model()->columnCount();//get count of columns
    for (int i = 0; i < c; ++i)
    {
        ui->tableView->setColumnHidden(i,true);//hide all columns
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); ++i)
    {
        if(list.at(i) < c)
            ui->tableView->setColumnHidden(list.at(i),false);//show columns which we want
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think for PyQt developers reading and understanding c++ code should be a must, so no problem that your code is in c++. Unfortunately, I have small rep so can't give you vote.